# add server side table content to div of aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
//ASPX PAGE
    <div id="nonPrintable">
         <table width="98%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" align="center">
               --
               --</table>          
     </div>
    <br/>
    <div id="printReport" runat="server">

    </div>
```

I am writng table from server side

```
Response.Write("<table width='95%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' align='center'>");
Response.Write("<tr class='tdcolbg'>");
Response.Write("<td>");***SOME CONTENT***
Response.Write("</td>");
Response.Write("</tr>");
Response.Write("</table>");
```

**I have add server side table content to div printReport How can i add it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using div use a label control and save the content in a stringbuilder object and then assign it to label text property. Example below

```
 // aspx code
<asp:Label ID ="lbReport" runat="server" />

// Code Behind
StringBuilder sbreport=new StringBuilder();
sbreport.Append("<table width='95%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' align='center'>");
sbreport.Append("<tr class='tdcolbg'>");
sbreport.Append("<td>");***SOME CONTENT***
sbreport.Append("</td>");
sbreport.Append("</tr>");
sbreport.Append("</table>");


lbReport.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: see the answer now. You have to write your complete html in a stingbuilder object.

Comment: which property ? you mean a value from datatable or any datasource ? you can directly put it in sbreport. like `string myvar="information"; sbreport.Write("<td> "+myvar+"</td>");`

Comment: there is append no write can i use append

Comment: sorry there is no write method, there is an append method. You have to use that. I updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a [`Repeater`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx)?

```
<div id="printReport" runat="server">
     <asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server">
      <HeaderTemplate>
         <table border="1">
            <tr>
               <td><b>Company</b></td>
               <td><b>Symbol</b></td>
            </tr>
      </HeaderTemplate>

      <ItemTemplate>
         <tr>
            <td> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %> </td>
            <td> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ticker") %> </td>
         </tr>
      </ItemTemplate>

      <FooterTemplate>
         </table>
      </FooterTemplate>

   </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have set your `printReport` div as a server control by adding `runat="server"` to it. 
add your table like this

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<table>");
```

and add it to control like this

```
printReport.innerHTML=sb.toString();
```